# JSON Parse empty results

Tags: php

I have the following example JSON:

```
{
productAPI: {
  status: 200,
  message: "OK",
  version: 3,
  products: {
    grouped: {
      matches: 773949,
      groups: [
        {
          doclist: {
            start: 0,
            numFound: 385957,
            docs: [
              {
                merchant: "Amazon",
                currency: "GBP"
               }
            ]
         },
         doclist: {
            start: 0,
            numFound: 885957,
            docs: [
              {
                merchant: "Ebay",
                currency: "GBP"
               }
            ]
         }
```

There will be multiple Merchant names I want to print but getting blank result (I am quite new to JSON parsing)

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$prodList=$prodList['productAPI']['products']['grouped']['groups']['doclist']['docs'];

foreach ($prodList as $element){
    echo $element['merchant'];
}
```

Is this the correct method?

**UPDATE**

As has been correctly pointed out (I didn't add enough example) 'groups' is an array, so, I've changed to the following but still no joy:

```
$prodList=$prodList['productAPI']['products']['grouped']['groups'];

$i=0;
foreach ($prodList as $element){
    echo $element[$i]['doclist']['docs']['merchant'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: `$prodList` where its defined? Did you `json_decode()`?

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes, its defined to bring in the data: $prodList = json_decode(file_get_contents('URL_HERE'),true);

Comment: Post your full JSON response please.

Answer (score 1):

Value under `groups` index is an array and you miss the index to this array. Maybe something like this would help:

```
$prodList=$prodList['productAPI']['products']['grouped']['groups'][0]['doclist']['docs'];
```

(depending on what can be in the `groups` array and what you want to do about it).

**Update**
Now there is conversely too much indirection to the `groups` array :). Try this:

```
$prodList=$prodList['productAPI']['products']['grouped']['groups'];
foreach ($prodList as $element){
    $docs = $element['doclist']['docs'];
    foreach ($docs as $doc) {
        echo $doc['merchant'];
    }
}
```